# Math to match series: 0, 90, 180, -90, 0, 90, 180, -90,

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

Some devices can't use rotation 270, so I want to convert it to -90

How can I make this series use `-90, 0, 90, 180` instead?

```
var val = 0;
    val = (val + 90) % 360; // 90
    val = (val + 90) % 360; // 180
    val = (val + 90) % 360; // 270
    val = (val + 90) % 360; // 0
```

Comment: Why not use an array with those values and then just increase a counter and mod 4.

Comment: `val = (val + 180) % 360 - 90;`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of shifting the modulo series `0..90..180..270`  by subtracting 90 at the end (generator function, but can be applied to anything else really, just shows the pattern)

```js
function *g() {
  let x = 0;
  while(true) {
    x = (x + 90) % 360;
    yield x - 90;
  }
}
let gen = g();
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  console.log(gen.next().value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add (almost) 180 before the modulus, and subtract it later.

Not exactly 180 because then you would get -180 instead of 180.

```js
var val = 0;
for(var i=0; i<8; ++i) {
  console.log(val = (val + 90 + 179) % 360 - 179);
}
```

Comment: that `179` can be anything between 90 and 179 (inclusive)... as you can see in the comment I made `val = (val + 180) % 360 - 90;`

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, but the number used determines the maximum value you can get, e.g. `(181 + 179) % 360 - 179 === -179`,  `(181 + 90) % 360 - 90 === 181`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I wondered why you chose such an odd number - I guess for this case though, it makes no difference as only the four cardinal points (0, 90, 180, -90|270) are of interest

Answer (score 0):

Here's another little trick to fool the processor:

```js
function toRad(deg){
  return deg * Math.PI / 180;
}

function toDeg(rad){
  return Math.round(rad * 180 / Math.PI);
}

function f(deg){
  var rad = toRad(deg);

  return toDeg(
           Math.round(Math.sin(rad))
           ? Math.asin(Math.sin(rad))
           : Math.acos(Math.cos(rad))
         );
}

var val = 0;

val = (val + 90) % 360; // 90 
console.log(val,f(val));

val = (val + 90) % 360; // 180 
console.log(val,f(val));

val = (val + 90) % 360; // 270 
console.log(val,f(val));

val = (val + 90) % 360; // 0
console.log(val,f(val));
```